# Windows Phone 8.1 Tile Wont Flip

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

How do I make my live tile for Windows Phone 8.1 Flip?

I have this piece of code, but have no clue where to add it. Or if there is anything else I need to implement.

```
    FlipTileData TileData = new FlipTileData()
    {
        Title = "[title]",
        BackTitle = "[back of Tile title]",
        BackContent = "[back of medium Tile size content]",
        WideBackContent = "[back of wide Tile size content]",
        Count = 2,
        SmallBackgroundImage = new Uri("/Assets/Tiles/ApplicationIcon.png", UriKind.Relative),
        BackgroundImage = new Uri("/Assets/Tiles/FlipCycleTileMedium.png", UriKind.Relative),
        BackBackgroundImage = new Uri("/Assets/Tiles/CycleImage1Medi.png", UriKind.Relative),
        WideBackgroundImage = new Uri("/Assets/Tiles/CycleTileLarge.png", UriKind.Relative),
        WideBackBackgroundImage = new Uri("/Assets/Tiles/CycleImage1Wide.png", UriKind.Relative),
    };
```

What am I suppose to do from here? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure whether this template of `FlipTileData` would apply for for WP 8.1.

This thread talks about the `live tiles` for WP 8.1.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thunbrynt/archive/2014/04/10/windows-phone-8-1-for-developers-live-tiles.aspx

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22858979/how-can-i-create-a-custom-live-tile-in-windows-phone-8-1) one could be a reference too.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you. I'll give it a try, and get back if it helps.