# How show informations in app icon on Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8

I'm developing a windows phone 8.1 app.

I would like, that when the user fixed my app on start screen, the icon show some informations. Like the calendar app.

I haven't found way for make this. Someone can help me?

Example on the calendar app:

[image: Wpf]

Answer (score 1):

You can create custom template using Windows Runtime app's [tile template catalog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh761491.aspx) which suites your requirement.

To know that How to create custom live tiles with custom formatted text on the secondary tile using Flip template which is default Tile template. You can find more general info about Tiles on Tiles for [Tiles for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh202948(v=vs.105).aspx) MSDN documentation.

**Referenes:**
[Windows Phone 8.1 for Developers–Live Tiles](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/thunbrynt/archive/2014/04/10/windows-phone-8-1-for-developers-live-tiles.aspx)
[Creating Custom Live Tiles for Windows Phone](http://spasol.wordpress.com/2013/06/24/creating-custom-live-tiles-for-windows-phone/)
[live tiles](http://www.wpcentral.com/tag/live-tiles)
[How can I create a custom live tile in Windows Phone 8.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22858979/how-can-i-create-a-custom-live-tile-in-windows-phone-8-1)